# JQUERY + Return an Array from a Function

Tags: jquery

I'm struggling to return an array from a function call - code below:

```
///////////// Generic Functions
function spotJoinPosition() {
    var pos = {  
                offset: $('div#spotJoinSite').offset(),                                
                width: $('div#spotJoinSite').width(),
                height: $('div#spotJoinSite').height()
    }
    return(pos);
}


        var positionData = spotJoinPosition();
        alert(positionData);
        alert(positionData[width]);
```

When I alert positionData I get [object][object] and then undefined.

Advice?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`alert(positionData[width]);`

This is alerting a key in positionData, and using the variable `width` as the key. You haven't defined a variable called `width`, so it's essentially looking up `positionData[undefined]`. What you want is `positionData.width`, or `positionData['width']`, but there is no reason for quotes here.

Quotes would only be required if you had a key with non alphanumeric characters. `positionData['some-key']` works, but `positionData.some-key` is a syntax error, because variables cannot have `-` in them.

Also, your code SHOULD be erroring, because width isn't defined anywhere. I'm worried that you have a globally defined `width` variable somewhere in your code.

Answer (score 1):

That's because `positionData` is an object (the object you return from `spotJoinPosition`) and <s>the variable `width` is undefined</s> the variable `width` contains a value that is not present on the object.

You want `positionData.width` or `positionData['width']`.

[See the MDN docs on member operators.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Member_Operators)

Comment: actually, the reason that `positionData[width]` is outputting `undefined` is because `width` *is* defined somewhere, but the value of `width` is not a valid key in his `positionData` object.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
  alert(positionData.offset);
  alert(positionData.width);
  alert(positionData.height);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you actually want a generic function that returns an `array` and not an `object`, you might want to revise to the following:

```
///////////// Generic Functions
function spotJoinPosition(selector) {
    var el = $(selector),
        result = [el.offset(), el.width(), el.height()];

    return(result);
}

var positionArray = spotJoinPosition("#spotJoinSite");
alert(positionArray[0]); // outputs the position
alert(positionArray[1]); // outputs the width
```